# What's a word for inspiring fraternity/camaraderie?

Tags: single-word-requests

Recently, I was attempting to describe the experience of traveling with strangers on one of those pedal trolleys which serve beer - how producing physical effort with others towards a shared goal inspires fraternity or camaraderie. I did some googling for `inspire synonyms` and a few searches along the lines of `inspiring fraternity,` but haven't been able to find the word I'm looking for.

It would be a synonym of inspire, with this added connotation of specifically inspiring fraternity.

Example sentence:

> Digging a ditch with another man ____ between the two of you.

Any clever linguists know a single word to describe this?

Comment: *Builds-esprit-de-corps*.

Comment: A single word is often not enough to explain an idea or action. The sentence is structured to use a noun (forms a "thing" between the two), but it seems you're looking for a verb. 
You could fill in the blank with "bonds" (and drop "between"). Other verbs that fit the idea: Unites, Joins, Ties, Links, Connects, and so on.

Comment: "Digging a ditch with another man *brought you closer to him*".

Comment: What's wrong with just using your own words? *Digging a ditch with another man **inspires camaraderie** between the two of you.*

Comment: Sounds a little what **cheer**leaders do

Answer (score 1):

> ***to bond**:*
>
> To form a friendship or emotional connection.
> *The men had bonded while serving together in Vietnam.*

[[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bond#Verb)]

In your sentence:

- Digging a ditch with another man *bonded* the two of you.

Comment: @Edwtin Ashworth - can't believe I forgot to add the link. Thanks!